# HttpClient Wrapper supports ignoring invalid/self-signed certs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the following as a wrapper for the HtptClient because it doesn't implement an interface -- which makes mocking more difficult. This logic also supports invalid and self-signed certs.

```
public class HttpClientWrapper : IHttpClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public Uri BaseAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return _client.BaseAddress;
        }

        set
        {
            _client.BaseAddress = value;
        }
    }

    public HttpRequestHeaders DefaultRequestHeaders
    {
        get
        {
            return _client.DefaultRequestHeaders;
        }
    }

    public HttpClientWrapper()
    {
        bool ignoreCertificateErrors = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IgnoreCertificateErrors"].ToBool();
        string environmentName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnvironmentName"];

        _client = new HttpClient();

        // If ignoreCertificateErrors config value is true, 
        // the setting ignores all Certificate validation errors in AppDomain, 
        // in every environment but PRODUCTION. 
        if (ignoreCertErrors && environmentName.ToUpper() != "PRODUCTION")
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        }
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, String userOrProcessName)
    {
        IUnityContainer container = UnityCommon.GetContainer();
        ILogService logService = container.Resolve<ILogService>();

        logService.Log(ApplicationLogTypes.Debug, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), userOrProcessName);

        return _client.SendAsync(request);
    }

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing && _client != null)
            {
                _client.Dispose();
            }

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

---

using the following for interface:

```
public interface IHttpClient : IDisposable
{
    Uri BaseAddress { get; set; }

    HttpRequestHeaders DefaultRequestHeaders { get; }

    Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, String userOrProcessName);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> bool ignoreCertificateErrors = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IgnoreCertificateErrors"].ToBool();
> string environmentName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnvironmentName"];
> ```

These two lines I think shouldn't be there because with them, the wrapper is tigthly coupled to the app.config.

I see three possibilities how you can decouple the wrapper:

- make both values constructor parameters if they shouldn't change
- make them properties if they can
- use the `UnityCommon` service locator that you use in the `SendAsync` method and let it resolve some `ConfigProvider` from which you can get both settings.

---

> ```
> environmentName.ToUpper() != "PRODUCTION"
> ```

Usually in situations like this it's safer to use a  case insensitive comparison

```
environmentName.Equals("PRODUCTION", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: better use string.Equals("PRODUCTION", environmentName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) to avoid NullPointerExceptions...

Comment: @Bernhard In some cases yes but here the config value should be validated before it's used so I assume it's not `null`.

Comment: how do you exactly validate your null? you use `null.ToUpper()` or `null.Equals()` ??

Comment: @Bernhard there are many ways to do this but I think the simplest one is to use the exception expression like `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] ?? throw new ...`.